# Receving 502 errors..please try again after 30 sec and frequent down of website throwing 502

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I am having a Big Website with huge traffic from users, issue was server was not able to handle by the other hosting providers even though with dedicated server with 16 gb of ram and now with GCP i am having same issue with high configuration and Here with GCP i am having a virtual machine setup in Google Cloud Platform with 2 instance created and a load balancer enabled and also having Google Cloud CDN enabled. But Now i am getting 502 errors please try again after.. Please try again in 30 seconds. which is making me irritating and for my users also and the main thing is i am not able to figure out whats the reason of 502 error which is thrown by server.

I jsut wanted to know whats going wrong here ... Is it with the load balancer issue which is caused by server miss configuration and raising 502? and one more thing i am having Fast CGI enabled and Memory limit increased php ini(Website running on Apache server and its a CMS) file and max Imput connection was set with higher limit (No prob with this) or is it with the traffic of the website or bots hitting the website which is causing the server to crash and throwing 502 error or it is that GCP is not able to handle with lot of queries and php process limits.

frequent 502 errors - Server is up for some time and after some times it throws 502 error its repeating.

Comment: Please post text results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '*_timeout'; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '*_size'.

Answer (score 1):

`502` means *Bad Gateway.*  It probably means your load balancer is not able to establish a connection with any of your web servers.

Can you try adding one or two more web server instances behind the load balancer?  As long as your system is configured to allow multiple web servers, you should be able to add more instances fairly cheaply. They all need to talk to the same MySQL server for Joomla! to do its thing correctly.

You might also want to look at the load balancer traffic and error logs. You're trying to spot information about what went wrong when the load balancer tried and failed to hit a web server.  Timeout? Refused connection? etc.

Are you using https?  If so, is the load balancer terminating https and passing http along to the web servers? If you can set things up that way, it can reduce the web server workload a lot.

You might also consider switching from apache to nginx. It scales up better in high-traffic situations.  But only do that as a cost-saving measure once you know that apache works OK with more web server instances behind the load balancer.